# Not able to scroll the listbox in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a listbox control where items are added using a user control having a textblock and image.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="52" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,10,0,0" Name="Index_itemtext" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
    <Image Height="34"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,55,0" Source="blue_triangle.png" Name="IndexList_itemImage" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" />
    <Line Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,38,0,0" Name="seperator_line" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF5E9E9" />
</Grid>
```

And the list box xaml:

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="768"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid  Opacity="5"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF282828" Offset="0.366" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FE848484" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>

        <Button  Content="Top" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="72"  Name="Top_btn"  Width="114"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="topbutton_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" >             
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF908585" Offset="0.11" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF342E2E" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <Button Content="Back" Height="72" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" Name="Back_btn" Width="104" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="backbutton_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" >
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF908585" Offset="0.11" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF342E2E" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>

            <ListBox Name="Index_list" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="on_selection" Margin="0,78,0,0" Height="Auto">
        <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">


        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>



</Grid>
```

Now when i add the items to the list ,the vertical scroll does not go till the last item/bottom of list box not reachable i.e. it comes back to first row which stops from last item selection:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
            {
                listbox_item list_item = new listbox_item();
                list_item.Index_itemtext.FontSize = 25;
                list_item.Index_itemtext.Text = index[i];
                list_item.IndexList_itemImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("some.png", UriKind.Relative));
                list_item.seperator_line.StrokeThickness = 5;
                list_item.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5);
                Index_list.Items.Add(list_item);
            }
```

Also the list row does not occupy the width of device in landscape mode,whereas the requirement is that the row item widens as the device width changes.Can someone help with these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having put the code that you've shown so far in a sample project I don't have the problems that you describe with scrolling, so I assume that there are other elements ont he page along with the `ListBox` that are affecting the layout and hence the scrolling.

As mentioned above, the problem with the orientation change was to do with fixed width elements, which you can resolve using star width columns as discussed in [Automatic Rotation Support or Automatic Multi-Orientation Layout Support for Windows Phone](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/04/08/automatic-rotation-support-or-automatic-multi-orientation-layout-support-for-windows-phone.aspx) ont he Windows Phone Developer Blog.

One other point worth making is that unless you actually have some logic related to this items that you have created the `listbox_item` `UserControl` for, you can implement the layout by specifying the `ItemTemplate` property of the `ListBox`, and then you can simply create a list of data objects and bind them to the `ItemsSource` property. E.g.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Index_list"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         Margin="0,78,0,0"
         SelectionChanged="on_selection"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
            <!-- Column definitions here. -->
            <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Image Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,55,0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" />
            <Line Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,38,0,0" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF5E9E9" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the landscape problem - You are setting the Width property on all your UserControl elements - so they will not autoscale.

On the scrolling issue, can you rephrase the question - sorry, but I'm not sure I understand the issue - "the vertical scroll does not go till the last item i.e. it comes back to first row which stops from last item selection" doesn't make sense to me - sorry

Comment: Sorry - still not clear to me. What does "not able to scroll" mean? Do you mean "the user cannot scroll the listbox"? Or do you mean "I want to programmatically select which item is currently shown"?

Comment: what i meant was that when user scrolls the list to rach the bottom item of list,it does not reach the bottom item in list.

Comment: can you post your entire page XAML? If you can't see the bottom of the ListBox then somehow that ListBox must be being positioned so that it's bottom is beyond the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Just for now... can you try removing the "row definitions" from your LayoutRoot - after you've done this, then I think your listbox will display fine. If that's the case, then you need to rewrite your Grid layout (perhaps readup about how to use "Auto" and "*")

Comment: Can you remove everything in your page except the ListBox? That way we can be sure that things like 'Height="768"' aren't interfering

Comment: OK - this is just debugging - if you've removed all formatting from the page, now remove all formatting (style, width, margin, etc) from  the usercontrol - eventually you'll get to something that works and that will tell you what's breaking it.

Comment: user control xaml does not have any style applied to it..and i have already tried by removing the margins ,width etc but its still the same

Comment: I suggest you try: running the wizard to create a new Pivot project - that contains a listbox that works well by default. Copy your code across bit by bit into that project - at what point does it fail. Other than that try posting an example project somewhere and people might be able to run it and see? Sorry - that's all I can suggest :/

Comment: Thanx a lot Stuart for ur help... I ll try it.

Answer (score 0):

The method [ListBox.ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28VS.95%29.aspx) allows you to scroll the ListBox to view a specific item. Also, with the WP7 ListBox if you select an item it is automatically scrolled into view.

Regarding your question on the with of the rows, you need to set the ListBoxItemsStyle as follows:

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
```

And remove your hard-coded widths in your template.

Comment: Thanx a lot for ur reply...I did wat u suggested but Still the bottom item of list is not reachable on scrolling.